# Website solution requires file not in version control

Tags: c#, version-control, projects-and-solutions

At my new job there is a C# website which relies on a `secrets.xml` file which is ***not*** in the version control repository. It contains links to databases and passwords. You need to copy it into the root directory manually.

Unfortunately, the existence of this secret file was not properly documented and I set up my solution without it. Worse, the solution builds and runs without it, and the website displays only a generic error when it needs to use the missing file, leading to developer misery.

Main question:

1. How can I ensure that the build breaks if the file is missing, so it's immediately clear what the problem is?

Follow-up questions:

2. What could be the rationale for not having the file in version control?
3. Is there a better way to achieve the objective in 2. than leaving it out of version control?

Comment: 1. if(! File.Exists(pathToFile) throw new FileNotFountException("todo");
3. use a pipeline in devops to add the credentials to the file

Comment: Thanks @Natrium. Is there a way to get the **build** to fail without the file, rather than the website?

Comment: For local developemnt you could use a prebuild condition which checks for the presence of the file and returns an errorcode when not found. I'm not sure whether or nor this is the best option. For building in devops, you could add a custom step to check for the file.

Comment: "*What could be the rationale for not having the file in version control?*" You didn't mention what version control system you use, but these days there's a good chance it's cloud-based. All it takes is one typo or misclick to inadvertently publish your repository publicly and now everyone has your secrets.xml file, leading to a security breach and the need to rotate all your secrets. Excluding such secrets from version control prevents that problem, and is therefore a _very_ common practice for cloud-based SVN repositories.